# "Cater to" vs. "cater towards"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I've heard both "cater to" and "cater towards" used, but I was wondering which one was correct. For example:

> - The event's theme seemed to cater to the artistic crowd.
> - The event's theme seemed to cater towards the artistic crowd.

Are there rules for this?  Which is correct?

Comment: They're both wrong. It should be *"The event's theme seemed to cater to the artistic crowd."* You can't say something *"is catered to"* something else, it can only *"cater to"* something.

Comment: Okay - edited.  I'm after the to/towards answer.

Comment: See the NGram link in my comment to Marcus's (incorrect) answer - it's always *cater to* (or *cater **for***), never *toward/towards*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want *cater to* here. I don't think you *cater toward* something.

You could say something like,"The event's theme seemed geared toward the artistic crowd." (In this case, *gear* would have the meaning "to adjust or adapt so as to make suitable.")

(Definitions from *The American Heritage Dictionary*, 4th Edition)

Answer (score 1):

This is pure opinion but I'd read "*cater to*" as meaning "intentionally designed for the artistic crowd" and "*catered toward*" as meaning "designed in a way that the artistic crowd would tend to appreciate, but not specifically designed for the artistic crowd"

Comment: No such distinction can be made with *cater*. Per [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cater+to%2Ccater+toward%2Ccater+towards&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3), neither *toward* nor *towards* occur after *cater* often enough to even be counted (they'd be "marked" usages if they ever did turn up).

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall ever seeing "cater towards", and its line on [Google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cater%20towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0)  is indistinguishable from zero to my eye. (There are some occurrences, but very few.)